# ActionText - How to specify the ActiveStorage service

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ActiveStorage allows for setting a 'service' for a class:

```
has_many_attached :images, service: :local
```

Is there a way to do that for `has_rich_text` or for actiontext as a whole?  I want to upload files to s3 across the app, but upload images in ActionText to a CDN.